# jodatime - PeriodFormatter: suffix only for day/days

Tags: java, android, jodatime, periodformatter

I need only to show suffix for day/days, how can I achieve that?
It doesn't work:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No field to apply suffix to..

```
    private PeriodFormatter getDayTextFormatter() {
        return new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .printZeroNever()
                .appendSuffix("day", "days")
                .toFormatter();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. According to [JodaTime's javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html#appendSuffix-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), the `appendSuffix` method will throw an exception if there's no field to append the suffix:

> Throws: IllegalStateException - if no field exists to append to

So I believe JodaTime can't help you this time. Although, you could do something like this:

```
private String suffix(Period p) {
    int days = p.getDays();
    if (days <= 0) {
        return "";
    }

    return days == 1 ? "day" : "days";
}
```

With this code, the following:

```
System.out.println(suffix(Period.days(1)));
System.out.println(suffix(Period.days(2)));
System.out.println(suffix(new Period()));
```

produces the output:

```
day
days
// and a line with an empty string
```

Comment: The easiest solution the best ;)

Comment: @AppiDevo Indeed!